# Migrate from Code Fluent to Entity Framework (.net)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, codefluent

I have a project done with Code Fluent and i want to change it with entity framework and so i want your help so i can convert this specific line

```
var authorizations = AuthorizationCollection.LoadAll(userId, companyId, subscriberId).ToList();
```

I did this as a start

```
   var authorizations = context.Authorization
```

but then what i need to do with the function and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the dbset to you context.cs file?

Something like var authorizations = context.Authorization.Where(x=>x.SubscriberId == subscriberId && x.UserId == userId && x.CompanyId == companyId).ToList()